# How to extract image from a live photo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, extract, phlivephoto

I know how to extract video from a live photo. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959973/extract-video-portion-from-live-photo).

Use the `PHAssetResourceManager` to get the video file from the `PHAssetResource`.

```
PHAssetResourceManager.defaultManager().writeDataForAssetResource(assetRes, 
    toFile: fileURL, options: nil, completionHandler: 
  {
     // Video file has been written to path specified via fileURL
  }
```

But how to extract image URL from PHLivePhoto. The motivation behind this is to get both video and image URL in order to upload it to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well assuming you have access to the PHAsset you can do something like the following:

```
[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil
                           completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
      NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write an image data to file path, just like with video in your question.
Both asset resources are available in live photo asset (video & image):

```
 let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)
```